# ¿Como puedo separar valores de una fila en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

El problema es el siguiente tengo una tabla como se muestra a continuacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es en la fila Institución separa en variables los campos con valor diferente y juntar los que son iguales

Quiero que en una consulta me muestre como acontinuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Esto es posible con MySQL?

Comment: no me parece, y tampoco parece algo con mucho sentido.. tal vez con una tabla pivotante.. La pregunta seria para que? porque si es para arreglar un problema de una vista, no deberia solucionarlo SQL.

Comment: Necesito contar todas las instituciones que son iguales pero en valores diferentes lo puedo hacer en diferentes consultas pero no seria optimo

Comment: Podes agregar lo que intentaste? Contar se cuenta con un count. O no es contar la palabra ue buscabas.

Comment: ¿Podrías decir en otras palabras qué es _contar todas las instituciones que son iguales_ o cómo lo conseguirías con la salida que propones?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías:

- Hacer dos consultas con la opción **`group by`**
- O simplemente una y luego filtrarlos en dos arreglos cuando estés recorriendo las filas obtenidas